# inner join on multiple conditions when using a database link

Tags: sql, oracle

Could someone help me figure out why my inner join won't work when I try to use multiple conditions? I'm using a database link to connect my tables, and then using "and" for my second condition. When I only have the first inner join on a.E_id = b.eid it shows results but when I add the second condition it turns up blank...

my code:

```
select count(*) 
from table1@dblink a
inner join table2 b
   on a.E_id = b.eid 
   and a.BUS_ID = b.B_NUMBER
where b.pricing_system = 'M'
;
```

[image]

Comment: That syntax for `like` doesn't look right.

Comment: please provide sample data and desired output

Comment: @dfundako even when I do = instead of like it doesn't work

Comment: Which dbms you are using?

Comment: @KaziMohammadAliNur I'm using toad for oracle

Comment: @CatalinaRadu I have added an answer. But sample data with desired output would have help to better understand your problem.

Comment: @eshirvana I have added an example of the data but had to blur out some

Comment: @CatalinaRadu sample data for both tables o needed as well as  deisred ouput , aslo avoid pasting screenshots

Answer (score 0):

I have used wildcard character `%` with like operator. Try below query:

```
select count(*) 
from table1@dblink a
inner join table2 b
   on a.E_id = b.eid 
   and a.BUS_ID like '%'||b.B_NUMBER||'%'
where b.pricing_system = 'M';
```

Comment: Please share sample data for a.bus_id and b.b_number fro which this condition matches.

Answer (score 0):

If the inner join can't find records with the condition the result will be no rows.

If you want the rows even if the second condition doesn't match, then change it for Left join and change the condition for a Like

And if the 'M' character is in diferents positions of the field, then use the character '%'

You should use this:

```
select count(*) 
from table1@dblink a
Left join table2 b
   on a.E_id = b.eid 
   and a.BUS_ID = b.B_NUMBER
and b.pricing_system = '%M%';
```